# how to test function in controller scope executed by event

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

function in controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function(){

   $scope.f = function($event){
      $event.preventDefault();
      //logic
      return data;
   }
})

describe('MyController', function(){
    'use strict';
    var MyController,
        $scope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach($inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
       $scope = $rootScope.$new();
       MyController = $controller('MyController', {
          $scope: $scope
       })
    }));
})
it('should...', function(){
    //fire event and expect data
})
```

`$scope.f` function is used in directive, it can be executed by `ng-click="f($event)"`

what is right way for fire event in unit test?

Comment: Could you provide some more contextual information?

Comment: @EvanBechtol sorry, i hope now it is more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You don't need to fire the event. You have access to the scope, which has the function you want to test. This means you just execute the function, then assert. It will look something like this:

```
it('should call preventDefault on the given event', function(){
  var testEvent = $.Event('someEvent');
  $scope.f(testEvent);
  expect(testEvent.isDefaultPrevented()).toBe(true);
});
```

See the following:

- [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)
- [event.isDefaultPrevented()](http://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/)

**Full Spec**

Also - your `it` block should be inside your `describe` block, so that it has access to the `$scope` field. It should look more like this:

```
describe('MyController', function(){
  'use strict';
  var MyController,
      $scope;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach($inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MyController = $controller('MyController', {
      $scope: $scope
    })
  }));

  it('should call preventDefault on the given event', function(){
    var testEvent = $.Event('someEvent');
    $scope.f(testEvent);
    expect(testEvent.isDefaultPrevented()).toBe(true);
  });
})
```

**A Note About Structure**

Don't be afraid to use the `describe` blocks to structure your tests. Imagine you had another function on the `$scope` called `f2`, then you would probably want to partition your spec file up more like this:

```
describe('MyController', function(){
  'use strict';
  var MyController,
      $scope;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach($inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MyController = $controller('MyController', {
      $scope: $scope
    })
  }));

  describe('$scope', function() {
    describe('.f()', function() {
      // tests related to only the .f() function
    });

    describe('.f2()', function() {
      // tests related to only the .f2() function
    });
  });
})
```

This has the benefit that when a test fails, the error message you see is constructed based on the hierarchy of `describe` blocks. So it would be something like:

> MyController $scope .f() should call preventDefault on the given
>   event